# Как получить следующий день недели?

Tags: javascript

С помощью этого кода можно получить следующий день с месяцем?
С помощью этого кода я получаю день недели, но к числу не добавляется 1

```
var d = new Date();
var n = parseInt(d.getDay());
document.write(n+1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) возвращает порядковый номер дня недели указанной даты по местному времени, где 0 соответствует воскресенью, а 6 субботе. То есть, если день недели суббота, то при `n+1`Вы получите некорректное значение. Помимо этого, метод [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) и так возвращает целочисленное значение и его не нужно дополнительно приводить к числу.

Возвращает объект [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) для следующего дня:

```js
var getTomorrow = function(){
  var now = new Date();
  return new Date(
      now.getFullYear(),
      now.getMonth(),
      now.getDate() + 1,
      now.getHours(),
      now.getMinutes(),
      now.getSeconds());
};

var tomorrow = getTomorrow();
var options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
};
console.log(tomorrow.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', options));
```

Если параметризировать функцию, то можно и так:

```js
var getFutureDate = function(days){
  var now = new Date();
  return new Date(
      now.getFullYear(),
      now.getMonth(),
      now.getDate() + days,
      now.getHours(),
      now.getMinutes(),
      now.getSeconds());
};

var dateInMonth = getFutureDate(30);
var options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
};
console.log(dateInMonth.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', options));
```

На странице [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) имеется исчерпывающие примеры использования.

Answer (score 1):

Функция получает следующий день недели

```
function nextDay(x){
    var now = new Date();    
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + (x+(7-now.getDay())) % 7);
    return now;
}
```